# How to get matched key value from an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Tried to get matched key value from an Object. I am trying to get column values from a javascript and assign them to an array then trying to get that values, but it is not working. How to do it?

I am getting the object like below:

```
var arr=[];

var details={

admin.button:"Test1",
admin.search:"Test2",

admin.file.column.id:"ID",
admin.file.column.class:"Class Name",
admin.file.column.atd:"Standard",
admin.file.column.book:"Source",
admin.file.column.time:"Timing",

admin.file.edit.label:"DAS",
admin.file.edit.label:"IKD",
admin.file.edit.label:"IDM"

}


var values=details['admin.file.column'];

arr.push[values];

for(var i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){

console.log(arr[i].id);
console.log(arr[i].class);
console.log(arr[i].atd);
console.log(arr[i].book);
console.log(arr[i].time);

}

}
```

Comment: Can you write that in actual JavaScript? Do you mean `details = { admin: { button: "...",  }, ... }`?

Comment: @tadman: I am getting like this object in console.log. This object data coming from service

Comment: This isn't JavaScript. It's not JSON. Can you at least show something *plausibly* JavaScript or JSON?

Comment: @tadman: I do not know this is javascript or JSON. But i am getting like this only in my console.log

Comment: Tip: `console.log(JSON.stringify(details))`.  You also need to read up on [how to use objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: push is a method `arr.push[values]` should be `arr.push(values)`

Answer (score 0):

Your "details" variable is not valid JSON. It would have to look something like the following:

```
var details={
    admin:{
        button:"Test1",
        search:"Test2",
        file:{
            column:{
                id:"ID",
                class:"Class Name",
                atd:"Standard",
                book:"Source",
                time:"Timing"
            },
            edit:{
                label0:"DAS",
                label1:"IKD",
                label1:"IDM"
            }
        }
}
```

Accessing the values would then work like

```
let column = details.admin.file.column;
```

Comment: How to convert variable details like your object format?

Comment: if you mean you want to output variable attributes you can use details.admin.file["column"], where the String "column" can be a variable

Comment: OP has probably omitted the quotes in the object literal when posting here but it is not invalid to have `.` in the key. You just need quotes when creating a literal: `var details={ "admin.button" :"Test1" }`